# SOLR copyfield with prefix

Tags: solr, lucene

Is it possible to add a prefix to the copyfield value?

So I have different types of entities, I want to copy their id's to a field for the purpose of using it as a unique key. but the information comes from a database, so the keys might be the same for the different entities.

what I want to do is copy the "company_id" as '"company"+_databaseId' and entityt_id as '"entity"+_databaseId'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using DIH to load data to Solr, you can use [ScriptTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer)

```
<script><![CDATA[
    function addFields(row)    {
        var databaseId = row.get('databaseId');
        row.put(databaseId_'company'+, "value");
        return row;
    } 
]]></script>
```

And define a dynamic field :-

```
<dynamicField name="*_company" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

[CopyField](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) is just a command and used to copy one field to another. You can't add prefix to copyField. You can solve your problem by using dynamic fields. You can define fields as :

```
<dynamicField name="*_company" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_entity" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="database_ids" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Define the copyFields as :

```
<copyField source="*_company" dest="database_ids"/>
<copyField source="*_entity" dest="database_ids"/>
```

When you get item from the *company* table, index it as `company_id_company` and 
when you get it from *entity* table index it as `entity_id_entity` field. Then all the ids will be copied to the database_ids field.

Comment: I understand, but the company_id can be '1' and the entity_id can be '1' so they overlap. So I have to add some kind of prefix

Comment: Thats why i define two different dynamic fields for company and entity. you will index company as 1_company and entity as 1_entity using the dynamicFields i define above. Instead of prefix, i used suffix here to make differences between the ids.

Comment: I thought the *_company meant it would contain all the field which have a name with "something_company" ?

Comment: EXAMPLE:  name="*_i" will match any field ending in _i (like myid_i, z_i)